# How to connect react-native to peerjs server on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, heroku, peerjs

how to use PeerServer deployed on heroku, in react native

I watched a youtube tutorial where tutor connected his react-native app with peerserver on localhost:5000 and that worked. However, my peerserver is deployed on heroku, trying to connect my app to it the same way the tutor did isn't working. I get the error `[Error: Could not get an ID from the server.]` which comes from `peerServer.on('error', console.log)`

This is my react-native code

```
export const API_URI = 'https://mvmserver.herokuapp.com'


// Peer Config

const peerServer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: 'mvmserver.herokuapp.com',
    secure: false,
    port: 52129,
    path: '/mypeer'
})

peerServer.on('error', console.log)
// Socket config

export const socket = IO(`${API_URI}`, {
    forceNew: true
})

socket.on('connection', () => console.log('Connected client'))
```

This is how the tutor had his

```
export const API_URI = 'localhost:5000'


// Peer Config

const peerServer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '192.00.0.0.0',
    secure: false,
    port: 5000,
    path: '/mypeer'
})

peerServer.on('error', console.log)
// Socket config

export const socket = IO(`${API_URI}`, {
    forceNew: true
})

socket.on('connection', () => console.log('Connected client'))
```

My `peerserver.js` on heroku

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const socketio = require('socket.io')

const {ExpressPeerServer} = require('peer');

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = socketio(server).sockets

//Borderparser
app.use(express.json())

const customGenerationFunction = () =>     (Math.random().toString(36) + "0000000000000000000").substr(2, 16)

const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
    debug: true,
    path: '/',
    genderateClientId: customGenerationFunction
})

app.use("/mypeer", peerServer)

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connected')
    socke.on('join-room', ({roomID, userId}) => {
        socket.join(roomID)
        socket.to(roomID).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)
    })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: Did you check the firewall of your computer and also Heroku ?

Comment: i think the issue is that, the app doesn't connect to the server at all...`peerServer.on('error'), console.log)` outputs 'Lost connection to server'...as for firewall on heroku, I don't know about that, i've used heroku before with socketio & didn't have this issue